# Partial floatification - is it possible?

Tags: programming, numerics, evaluation

Suppose, I have a system of equations like

```
2y[Pi] + 3 y[E] == Sqrt[7]

3 y[Pi] + EulerGamma y[E] == Zeta[3]
```

Now, I want a numerical solution to this, but I don't want to `N[]` the arguments of `y[]`. Is there some elegant way to do this?

(Of course, the real point of this is is to solve very large systems which come from numerical solution of integral equations).

Comment: You should really provide an evaluatable example. At any rate, perhaps you could use `SetAttributes[y, NHoldAll]`?

Comment: @CarlWoll In what sense is the example not evaluable?

Comment: Except for a typo.

Comment: `2 y[Pi] + 3 y[E] = Sqrt[7]` produces a `Set::write` error message.

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, I missed a close paren.

Comment: Did you really intend to use `=` and not `==`, considering that you were talking about solving equations?

Comment: @J.M. Oy, gevalt.

Comment: @J M for god's sake, I gave a 2x2 system so it would be easy to duplicate, if you cared, but really just to illustrate the question.

Comment: Also, `EulerGamma` is a constant and not a function... anyway, Carl's suggestion is the canonical method.

Comment: I don't see why `N[]` has to be used at all.  Either `NSolve` or `FindRoot`, or maybe something with `LinearSolve` if it's a linear system.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Did you read the last sentence. Do you know how long it would take to solve a large SYMBOLIC linear system. If not, I encourage you to try.

Comment: @CarlWoll I just got home it tried it - HoldAll does NOT prevent the argument of y from being floated.

Comment: I'm suggesting numerical solutions....Why do you say SYMBOLIC? You yourself say "numerical solution."

Comment: Try NHoldAll instead!

Comment: @Michael, I'm getting the impression that this is the route Igor is taking in discretizing an integral equation, and he wants indexed variables that are unaffected by `N[]`. (He really should be using matrices anyway, but that's neither here nor there.)

Comment: @J.M ". Using matrices is probably what I will wind up doing, but discretizing "symbolically" is more morally pure, and also more general (it will work for non-linear problems too, at least in principle). In my case, the integral equation is two-dimensional, and laziness makes one prefer that mathematica do the work of working out the structure of the matrix. . As for Michaell's question, LinearSolve with coefficients like E and Pi^2/17 might as well be symbolic (not entirely true, if the transcendence degree is finite over Q, the computation will be polynomial, but of high degree).

Comment: @CarlWoll That works!

Comment: That's what he said in the very first comment! :D

Comment: By "***something*** with LinearSolve" I was thinking the matrix would be numericized at an appropriate point, thereby avoiding problems with `y[..]`. (It wasn't clear at first that it was a linear system.) Something like `Thread[vars -> LinearSolve[Last[#], -First[#]]&@N@CoefficientArrays[sys /. Equal -> Subtract, vars]]`. It's what `NSolve` should do eventually more or less, but `NSolve`, which seems quite a bit slower than `LinearSolve`, might be spending some time symbolically analyzing the system first.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, reading comprehension issues.

Answer (score 2):

I use code similar to that below to get inside certain heads but avoid those that are not of interest for purposes of numericization. When the list of heads to exclude is concise, the approach of making them `NHoldAll` is probably better. When it is the other way around, where the heads to go inside consist of numeric functions and a few others, then the method below is useful.

```
relHeads = {Equal, Unequal, Inequality, Greater, GreaterEqual, Less, 
   LessEqual};
resetPrecision[
  ee_List | (ee : a_Symbol[b___] /; 
     MemberQ[relHeads, a]) | (ee : a_Symbol[b___] /; 
     MemberQ[Attributes[a], NumericFunction]), prec_] := 
 Map[resetPrecision[#, prec] &, ee]
resetPrecision[a_?NumericQ, prec_] := SetPrecision[a, prec]
resetPrecision[a_, prec_] := a
```

Examples:

```
resetPrecision[2 y[Pi] + 3 y[E] == Sqrt[7], 20]

(* Out[126]= 
3.0000000000000000000 y[E] + 
  2.0000000000000000000 y[\[Pi]] == 2.6457513110645905905 *)

resetPrecision[
 3 y[Pi] + EulerGamma y[E] == Zeta[3], MachinePrecision]

(* Out[132]= 0.577215664902 y[E] + 3. y[\[Pi]] == 1.20205690316 *)
```